# mod_rewrite does not rewrite with encoded URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am currently developing a PHP-backend using a simple router (in the index.php file).
Now I have a REST-Call to a route, containing a url-encoded url like this:

```
https://api.example.com/{encoded url}/information
```

Example: `https://api.example.com/https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fcategory%2Fexample-slug/information`

My `.htaccess`-file, that should redirect all calls to the index.php file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]

RewriteRule !^index\.php$ index.php [L]
```

Now the problem is, that when accessing such a route, the Apache-Server shows me the default 404 page, meaning the request was not redirected to the index.php file. It seems like the encoded `/` (`%2F`) are the problem, but I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is the encoded slashes directive of Apache, as per @CBroe's comment:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes